# Is there a way to grant EXECUTE permissions on server-level objects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, ssms

I have a user on a database which cannot have database-level permissions assigned to it seeing that they are wiped periodically but the user needs to execute on certain stored procedures within said database so that he can import data properly.

What I am currently doing is running `GRANT EXECUTE ON certain.storeProcedure TO user` every time the permissions are wiped, but this isn't the most elegant solution.

However, server-level permissions are not wiped in the same way. There is the `Alter Database` permission, but that is too broad for my needs.

Also, I did find [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16), but I cannot parse the tables within it.

So my question is: Is there a way to emulate the database-level `EXECUTE` permission using server-level permissions while being as restrictive as possible?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but can the process that re-creates the user also re-grant the permissions? One thing that would make that easier is to encapsulate those permissions in a user-defined role at which point the only thing that needs doing after re-creating is to add them to that role.

Comment: @BenThul The job that wipes the permissions is outside of my purview and I have no access to creating jobs on this server.

Comment: Why are the database level permissions on this user being wiped periodically? If the user needs these permissions, then whoever is responsible for the process which is removing those permissions is the person you need to talk to, surely?

Comment: @3N1GM4 THey are being wiped by a third-party script which I have no control over.

Comment: You might have no control over it, but if a 3rd party is removing legitimate user permissions on a database, then someone in your organisation surely needs to remedy that, rather than you finding a workaround to re-implement the permissions every time it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Grant execute on an object is done at the database level.  However, if the other solutions above don't work, you could set up a SQL job to re-set it each morning.